# getting bubble sort to work with structure

Tags: c, sorting, struct

im not sure how to bubble sort using structures, id like the function sortMovies to be able to sort the movies alphebeticaly by title but i am getting these errors listed below.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define CONST 100
void sortMovies(struct movies main[CONST]);
void changeMovie(struct movies main);
int findMovie(struct movies main, int nOfMovies, struct movies tempMovie);
struct movies newMovie();
typedef struct movies{
    char title[30];
    char UPC[12];
    int qnty;
    double price;
}movies;

int main()
{
    int nOfMovies = 0, findR, stop = 0, nOfMoviesArr[CONST];
    char decider;
    while (stop != 1)
    {
        movies main[CONST];
        movies tempMovie;
        printf("(A)dd a new movie\n(C)hange a Movie's Information \n(D)elete a Movie \n(L)ist All Movies\n(Q)uit");
        scanf(" %c", &decider);

        switch (decider)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            tempMovie = newMovie();
            nOfMovies = findMovie(main[CONST], nOfMovies, tempMovie);
            nOfMovies++;
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            printf("enter movie upc:");
            scanf("%s", main);

            break;
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            sortMovies(main[CONST]);
            break;
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("An invalid option was selected!");
        }
    }


}

struct movies newMovie() {
    movies new;

    printf("enter movie upc:");
    scanf("%s", new.UPC);
    printf("enter movie title:");
    scanf("%s", new.title);
    printf("enter movie qauntity:");
    scanf("%d", new.qnty);
    if (new.qnty <= 0)
    {
        printf("quanitity must be greater than 0");
        printf("enter movie qauntity:");
        scanf("%d", new.qnty);
    }

    printf("enter movie price:");
    scanf("%lf", new.price);
    if (new.price <= 0)
    {
        printf("price must be greater than 0");
        printf("enter movie price:");
        scanf("%lf", new.price);
    }
    return new;
}


int findMovie(struct movies main, int nOfMovies, struct movies tempMovie)
{

    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < nOfMovies; count++)
    {
        if (tempMovie.UPC == main.UPC)
        {
            return count;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error");
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
void changeMovie(struct movies main)
{
    char decider;

    printf("would you like to change the value? y or no input");
    switch (decider)
    {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        printf("enter movie title:");
        scanf("%c", main.title);
        printf("enter movie qauntity:");
        scanf("%d", main.qnty);
        if (main.qnty <= 0)
        {
            printf("quanitity must be greater than 0");
            printf("enter movie qauntity:");
            scanf("%d", main.qnty);
        }

        printf("enter movie price:");
        scanf("%lf", main.price);
        if (main.price <= 0)
        {
            printf("price must be greater than 0");
            printf("enter movie price:");
            scanf("%lf", main.price);
        }
        break;

        return 0;

    }

}
void sortMovies(struct movies main[CONST])
{
    int i, sflag, count = 0;
    char temp;

    do
    {
        sflag = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < CONST; i++)
        {
            if (main[i - 1].title > main[i].title)
            {
                temp = main[i - 1].title;
                main[i - 1].title = main[i].title;
                main[i].title = temp;
                sflag = 1;
            }
        }
        count++;
    } while (sflag);

    for (i = 0; i < CONST; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\t%c\t%d\t%lf", main[i].title, main[i].UPC, main[i].qnty, main[i].price);
    }


} ```
````

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   C2440   'function': cannot convert from 'movies' to 'movies *'      40
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "movies" is incompatible with parameter of type "struct movies *"      40
Error (active)  E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue      148
Error   C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value   148
Error (active)  E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue      149
Error   C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value   149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error (active) E0167 argument of type "movies" is incompatible with parameter of type "struct movies *" 40

This is happening because with `main[CONST]` you are trying to pass a single element of of the `main` array (the element at index `CONST`), rather than the whole array when the `sortMovies` method expects an array. To pass the whole array into the function, use `sortMovies(main);`.

> Error (active) E0137 expression must be a modifiable lvalue 148
>   Error C2106 '=': left operand must be l-value 148
>   Error (active) E0137 expression must be a modifiable lvalue 149
>   Error C2106 '=': left operand must be l-value 149

This is happening because you are trying to copy the contents of one char array to another with the `=` operator, which is not valid. Instead, use `strcpy(main[i - 1].title, main[i].title)` and `strcpy(main[i].title, temp)`.

Also, in your `sortMovies` function you declare `temp` as a char which you try to use to swap the `title` strings. What you want here is instead `char* temp`. If you are not familiar with this syntax, I would recommend reading up on pointers in C. They are a very important construct in the language, and a better understanding of pointers will likely also help you clear up a lot of the issues you are having with this program.